# netplan set-name option not working on Freshly Installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop Image on Vmware machine

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, vmware

I need to change network card kernel assigned name ens34 to buslan0. However, using the set-name option in netplan config, which matches the device by MAC address, does not work. The OS is fresh install of Ubuntu desktop 18.04 on a virtual machine hypervisor Vmware Workstation Pro.

OS:
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
ubuntu desktop 5.3.0-53-generic #47~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 13:10:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

This is my netplan configuration:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
 network:
      version: 2
      renderer: NetworkManager
      ethernets:
        buslan0:
          dhcp4: no 
          addresses: [128.204.10.15/24]
          gateway4: 128.204.10.15
          nameservers:
            addresses: [127.0.0.1, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
          match:
            macaddress: 00:50:56:3f:56:d5
          set-name: buslan0
```

This is my current network

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens34: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::8103:e788:ac46:e31a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I execute

```
sudo netplan apply 
sudo reboot
```

I expect ens34 to be buslan0 and have the corresponding ip address of 128.204.10.15. However, when the virtual machine boots up it still shows the same current network.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens34: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::8103:e788:ac46:e31a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, when I remove the set-name option and use this configuration instead

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    ens34:
      dhcp4: no 
      addresses: [128.204.10.15/24]
      gateway4: 128.204.10.15
      nameservers:
        addresses: [127.0.0.1, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:3f:56:d5
      # set-name: buslan0
```

Then execute the following command(s)

```
sudo netplan apply 
sudo reboot #optional
```

My network status is

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens34: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 128.204.10.15/24 brd 128.204.10.255 scope global noprefixroute ens34
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**How can I reliably change my interface name?**

Further edits:
I decided to test this on a new fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 with the last updates as of the time of this writing. I created two snapshots prior to messing with netplan:
This my network status prior to different YMAL configs

```
$ ifconfig
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.228.140  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.228.255
        inet6 fd15:4ba5:5a2b:1008:36c2:ccfe:4c83:5f65  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::7871:1aa8:f5f7:3cc0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd15:4ba5:5a2b:1008:d108:59df:ac5d:f3d4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:50:56:37:aa:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12  bytes 1370 (1.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 69  bytes 9422 (9.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::527c:66a3:baf4:9ae4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31  bytes 4145 (4.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 122  bytes 9601 (9.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 122  bytes 9601 (9.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Thne on one snapshot I tried this YMAL configuration

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens34:
      addresses: [128.204.10.15/24]
      gateway4: 128.204.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:3f:56:d5
      set-name: buslan0
```

followed by these commands

```
 ~$ sudo netplan --debug generate
    ~$ sudo ifconfig ens34 down
    ~$ sudo netplan apply

~$ ifconfig
buslan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 128.204.10.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 128.204.10.255
        inet6 fe80::5c1:b817:995c:58fb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 109  bytes 15353 (15.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.228.140  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.228.255
        inet6 fd15:4ba5:5a2b:1008:36c2:ccfe:4c83:5f65  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::7871:1aa8:f5f7:3cc0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd15:4ba5:5a2b:1008:ac17:14d4:1aee:3e25  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:50:56:37:aa:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 51  bytes 6869 (6.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 159  bytes 19464 (19.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 243  bytes 20571 (20.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 243  bytes 20571 (20.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    ~$ reboot
```

network status after reboot

```
:~$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 42  bytes 3817 (3.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 42  bytes 3817 (3.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

~$ ifconfig -a
buslan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:37:aa:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 42  bytes 3817 (3.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 42  bytes 3817 (3.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

With this YMAL file on the other snapshot

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens34:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:50:56:3f:56:d5
  bridges:
    buslan0:
      addresses: [128.204.10.15/24]
      gateway4: 128.204.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
      interfaces:
        - ens34
      macaddress: 00:50:56:3f:56:d5
```

followed by these commands

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan apply
~$ ifconfig
buslan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 128.204.10.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 128.204.10.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe3f:56d5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 177  bytes 11478 (11.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.228.140  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.228.255
        inet6 fd15:4ba5:5a2b:1008:213b:6d49:9722:144f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::7871:1aa8:f5f7:3cc0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd15:4ba5:5a2b:1008:36c2:ccfe:4c83:5f65  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:50:56:37:aa:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1327  bytes 1379455 (1.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1018  bytes 88809 (88.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 245  bytes 24496 (24.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 336  bytes 28905 (28.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 336  bytes 28905 (28.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
reboot
```

After reboot this my network status

```
~$ ifconfig
buslan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 128.204.10.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 128.204.10.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe3f:56d5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78  bytes 7773 (7.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:3f:56:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78  bytes 8021 (8.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 67  bytes 6124 (6.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 67  bytes 6124 (6.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The takeaway here is that as soon as I reboot I lose internet connectivity. However before each reboot and after sudo netplan apply, I am able to achieve my goal of changing the interface name to something of my choosing.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through this [post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1768827) I found a solution which I used

> 1. netplan apply
> 2. cp /run/systemd/network/*.link /etc/systemd/network/
> 3. update-initramfs -u
> 4. reboot # all is well now
>
> The point is that it forces the renaming to be applied early, in the
>   initramfs, and this seems to be sufficient for the interface to be
>   configured and brought up during boot. I have verified that the
>   renaming happens early now - and did not before this work around - by
>   using `break=mount` on the kernel command line.